# Qr barcode using Wpf

Tags: wpf, barcode, decode

Has anyone worked with QR barcode using WPF? Is there a free library for Wpf?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? QR codes don't have anything to do with WPF directly.

Comment: Hi,I need a QR code library for my wpf application. In previous project I used BarcodeLib library in win forms app,but that library doesn't work in wpf, on the other hand is quite expensive. I neeed some free solution...

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I used QRCode Library. You may want to check it out. It is not specific to WPF, but it generates a bitmap that you can use in your WPF app: http://twit88.com/platform/projects/show/mt-qrcode

Comment: Hi, I saw your solution and I can to decode QR barcode,but I can't to encode some data in barcode. There is probably  a litle bug.

Comment: "Index was outside the bounds of the array" that's exception displayed when I try to encode data. How to resolve problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a WPF wrapper for [QrCode.Net](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/). I'm going to submit the code to the project, but for now you can get the code you need from https://gist.github.com/1353306